# change a db from a certain point in time, when the change doesn't fit the already existing data

Tags: database, django, database-design

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    updater = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ... and so on...
```

There are some more fields but they are irrelevant to the question. Now the site has very simple functions - the users can see older reports and their data, and can edit them or add new ones.

However, the identifier field is actually an integer that symbolizes a log file that is being reported. Most of the times, each report has one log. But sometimes it has more than one. I did it as a CharField because I built the site to replace an older sharepoint 2003 website, where that field was treated as simple text. So I want that in my next version, it would be like it should be, i.e. like this:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    updater = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    ... and so on...

class Log(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    identifier = models.IntegerField()
```

The problem is, since in the old site that field was a CharField, people used this as they liked. Meaning, even if they updated various logs in the same report they just did it like this `<logid1>, <logid2>`. Sometimes they added some text `<logid1> which is related to <logid2>`.

So I want to change this, but I don't want to lose all the old data, and I can't fix all those edge cases (the DB contains around 22 thousand reports). I thought about adding this to report:

```
def disp_id(self):
    if self.pub_date < ... #the day I'll do the update
        return self.identifier
    else:
        return ', '.join([log.identifier for log in self.log_set.all()])
```

But then I'm not really getting rid of the old field now am I? I'm just adding a new one and keeping the original null from a certain date.

As far as I know, what I want to do is impossible. I'm only asking because I know that maybe I'm not the first one to deal with this sort of thing and maybe there is a solution that I'm not aware of.

Hope my explanation is clear enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite following...so you essentially want to rename the existing `Log` model to `Report` and create a new `Log` model, meaning the proposed `Log` model (regardless of the name) doesn't currently exist?  Also, what database backend are you using?

Comment: Mysql. The names of the models themselves do not matter, it's just that one field that I want to change to a foreignKey

Comment: Still not getting it, the names of the models/fields matter if you want to do some data migration. Your `disp_id()` method in `Report` shows `self.identifier` but there is no `identifier` field shown for that model.

Comment: you're right, the explanation was confusing. I re-wrote the entire thing, hope that's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

```
class Report(models.Model):
    updater  = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    identifier = models.CharField(null=True)
    ... and so on...
    logs     = models.ManyToManyField(Log,null=True)

class Log(models.Model):
    identifier = models.IntegerField()
```

Make the above model , and then make a script as follow:

```
ident_list = []
for reports in Report.objects.all():
    identifiers = reports.identifiers.split(',')
    for idents in identifiers:
        if not idents in ident_list:
            log = Log.create(**{'identifier' : int(idents)})
            ident_list.append(int(idents))
        else:
            log = Log.objects.get(identifier = int(idents))
        report.log.add(log)
```

Check the data before removing the column identifiers from the table Report.
Does it solves your purpose now ?

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem.  I'm not asking what type of relationship to use, I'm asking how to turn a CharField to a ForeignKey and the best way to do that without losing my data

Comment: i re-wrote the question, look again maybe you'll understand what I wanted better

Comment: I want to know , that the char field earlier was storing strings like "<log1>,<log2>" or you had duplicate entries for every identifier.

Comment: no duplicates, just sometimes more than one. And the format wasn't always '<log1>, <log2>', that's the entire problem. Every user did something different and it's all a big mess

Comment: It is still confusing. In new version do you have identifier in Report or not ? Please elaborate the difficulties you are facing while converting the field to foreign key . Please add some sample data that makes the conversion difficult

Comment: I want not to have identifier in report but I also don't want to lose all the data. The only way I can think of is adding the Log class with a foreign key (for future reports), and keeping the identifier field just for the old data. I know the problem is a bit convoluted, I really don't know how to make it any clearer

Comment: One last thing , in the earlier entries does the identifier consist of many char field identifier seperated by comma(,) . For eg: identifier can be = 'tech,industry,apple' and you want to separately store the identifier in 3 separate entries each for apple , industry and tech . Right ?

Comment: yes. But it's more complicated. Because each identifier is a number and everyone did whatever they wanted. So I don't have a simple case of '1234, 4232, 3213' I have a million edge cases where its '1234 that relates to 4323 and 3213' and also '1234, 4232,' and '1234 (ext)'

Comment: I had changed the answer an hour ago, did you had a look ? Could that be useful ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but like I said, I want to try and avoid a script that fixes it like that. My python is pretty good, I know already how to make something like that, but there are many edge-cases and I wanted to try and avoid that sort of solution. I was thinking more in the way of a special db desing or tool that I might not be familiar with. I think that what I'm hoping for is impossible. But thanks again for all you effort. I really appreciate it